# Vuesax router link

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuesax, vuesax-4

How to create a vuesax router link? Any answer would be appreciated.
What I tried: Adding `to="/path"` to `vuesax-navbar__item`, but it does not trigger class change.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/#router) documentation, it describes the router support for the button.

> You can send a string or object to directive to. This directive wrap a $router.push() vue method, you can use all programmatic navigation on vue router.

```
String literal Object Path Named Router With Query
<vs-button color="primary" type="filled" to="/components/list.html">String literal</vs-button>
<vs-button color="warning" type="filled" :to="{ path: '/components/list.html' }">Object Path</vs-button>
<vs-button color="success" type="filled" :to="{ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 } }">Named Router</vs-button>
<vs-button color="dark"    type="filled" :to="{ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' } }">With Query</vs-button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that these docs do not work for the fourth version